# How can I put a URL instead of an IP address in Azure Hosted application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi I have hosted my aplication through IIS on Azure Virtual Machine.Now the generated link for access looks like this :

*http://13.76.241.183/xyzApplication*

However, I want it to look like:

*https://CloudApp.net.xyzApp/xyzApplication*

Any Fixes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your virtual machine a classic VM or ARM VM? 
The above answer is correct for classic Virtual machine.
There is no concept of cloud service in ARM VMs so your url becomes something like 
(DomainNamelabel).(location).cloudapp.azure.com

Please check -
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2015/05/05/creating-azure-vms-with-arm-powershell-cmdlets/

UPDATE- For ARM VM, if you go to the portal, click on VM and then in the essentials click on the links under Public IP address/DNS name label, you will open a blade which will show you the complete link

Comment: Thanks again for the exceptional case.

Comment: yup ;)..we figured out ur solution worked as we are from south-west asian region...thats what appeared in URL too. :)

Comment: ya sure, i dont have that priveledge yet.If you can upvote my question, I can do that.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. If I use ip address it works fine but If I use DNS name. It will through url mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

Your virtual machine should have a service name, i.e. mywebserver.cloudapp.net, to which you can reference it.

It is usually the VM name that is the service name, or something like it. 
If you log on to manage.windowsazure.com, find your VM, and click "Dashboard", you will see it's DNS name on the right bottom part of the dashboard screen.